# How to switch from one Astro 3 template to another template without deleting the project

Tags: astrojs

I have just started with Astro 3.0 and realised that I've installed the default template.

Instead of deleting the project I just created, is there a way to switch to another template?

I want to switch to: [Portfolio](https://github.com/withastro/astro/tree/main/examples/portfolio)